# Using 'with' in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

My friend had a few presentations and I would like to say him:

> I wish you did well [**with**] your presentations.

Should I use with or maybe 'of' in the sentence?

Comment: Don't worry about the preposition (*with*, *in*, or even *at* are fine here). The problem word is ***wish***, which should be ***hope***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If he hasn't given the presentations yet, you could say one of these:

> I wish you well with your presentations.
>   I hope you do well on your presentations.

I think either *with* or *on* could work in this context. However, it might be better not to use a preposition at all:

> I hope your presentations go well.

---

If he has already given the presentations, you would say:

> I hope your presentations went well.

You might also use *with* or *on*, but you could even use *during*:

> I hope everything went well during your presentations.

---

Notice how I used *hope* instead of *wish* for most of these examples. For the most part, *hope* is the better word to use, unless you are using the idiom *wish (someone) well*.

Comment: +1 *Wish* can also be used with counterfactuals: *I wish you had done well instead of screwing the pooch*.